Batch file to rename added files to continue sequence of files already in folder
I'm trying to make a batch script that will rename both image files (.jpg .jpeg .png) and video files (.avi .flv .mp4 .mpg .mpeg .qt .webm .wmv) files to a numeric sequence or continue a pre-existing sequence. For example, if I have three image files named
test.jpeg
sample.png
image.jpg
when the script runs, they should be renamed as
1.jpeg
2.png
3.jpg
But if there are files already in the folder, named
0001.png
0002.jpg
0003.jpeg
then the new files should continue the sequence and be renamed as
0004.jpeg
0005.png
0006.jpg
If the pre-existing files in the folder have a prefix, say
T-0001.png
T-0002.jpg
T-0003.jpeg
the new files should be renamed with that prefix:
T-0004.jpeg
T-0005.png
T-0006.jpg
But I want it to work for whatever prefix comes before the four digit number that the files already in the folder happen to have. It would also be ideal if the script would work for any number of digits rather than just four. For instance, if a folder has 9 video files of various names, they should be renamed as 1-9. If the folder has 10 video files, they should be renamed as 01-10. If the folder has 100 video files, they should be renamed as 001-100, etc. Or if there is a pre-existing sequence Example 001, the script should rename all files that don’t begin with the prefix Example continuing the sequence with Example 002. But if the pre-existing sequence has three leading zeros like Example 0001, the script should rename all files that don’t begin with the prefix Example continuing the sequence with Example 0002. So I’d like the script to be able to create a sequence based on the number of files that are already in the folder (if there is not already a prefix before the number), and if there is already a sequence, I want the script to continue that sequence regardless of how many leading zeros the pre-existing sequence has. The pre-existing files in the folder will sometimes have text after the number, for example, A-0001 - Test or 001 (Sample) so the script needs to allow for that.
Mofi has created this script, which works perfectly for image files that begin with T-. However, like I explain above, I'd like this script to work for whatever pre-existing files are in the folder, regardless of what prefix they have (or none at all, like if it’s just a numeric sequence), and for both image files (.jpg .jpeg .png) and video files (.avi .flv .mp4 .mpg .mpeg .qt .webm .wmv) files. I know how to make it work for video files. I just need to add the video extensions .avi .flv .mp4 .mpg .mpeg .qt .webm .wmv to the lines with the image extensions. But I do not know how to do the rest of what I want. Please help! Thank you!
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the file number with initial value 0.
set "FileNumber=0"

rem Find the highest number in T-* image file names.
for /F "tokens=2 delims=-.()_ " %%I in ('dir T-*.jpg T-*.jpeg T-*.png /A-D-L /B /O-N 2^>nul') do set "FileNumber=%%I" & goto HaveNumber

rem Remove all leading zeros from the highest file number for getting the
rem file number value interpreted as decimal and not as octal number. It
rem is possible that the environment variable FileNumber is not defined
rem anymore after this operation on still having the initial value 0 which
rem does not matter for the following code. The arithmetic expression used
rem next with FileNumber uses value 0 on no environment variable FileNumber
rem defined on evaluation of the arithmetic expression.

:HaveNumber
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%I in ("%FileNumber%") do set "FileNumber=%%I"

rem Is there any file system entry with an exclamation mark?
if exist "*!*" goto ExtendedRename

rem It is possible to use permanently enabled delayed variable expansion
rem as there is no file system entry with an exclamation mark in name.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Rename new image files of which name does not beginn case-insensitive
rem with T-. It is important to get first all file names to change loaded
rem into the memory of the running CMD process before starting the rename
rem operation as otherwise it could happen, especially on FAT32 and exFAT,
rem formatted storage medias, that a file is skipped or there is tried to
rem rename a file more than once.

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.jpg *.jpeg *.png /A-D-L /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /L /V /C:"T-"') do (
    set /A FileNumber+=1
    set "NextNumber=000!FileNumber!"
    ren "%%I" "T-!NextNumber:~-4!%%~xI"
)

endlocal
goto EndBatch

rem There is at least one directory, file or link which contains an exclamation
rem mark. It is necessary for that reason to get first assigned the file name
rem to an environment variable while delayed variable expansion is disabled
rem for getting the exclamation mark interpreted as literal character and not
rem as beginning/end of a delayed expanded variable reference and then enable
rem the required delayed variable expansion, rename the file and disable it
rem again. This is slower because of the memory copy operations done in the
rem background on every execution of setlocal and memory free operations on
rem every execution of endlocal.

:ExtendedRename
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.jpg *.jpeg *.png /A-D-L /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /L /V /C:"T-"') do (
    set "FileName=%%I"
    set /A FileNumber+=1
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "NextNumber=000!FileNumber!"
    ren "!FileName!" "T-!NextNumber:~-4!%%~xI"
    endlocal
)

:EndBatch
endlocal


You never increment the highest variable. If there is more than 1 file to rename you have to add 1 to the highest variable otherwise the num variable will always be the same.

Best way to see your problem is to properly debug the code by using echo on at the top of your script and then execute the batch file from a cmd prompt. Do not use your mouse to execute the script.

You certainly do not need that many for commands to parse the highest number. Just substring the base filename.

The requirements for coding the batch file are much cleared with the edit on 2024-04-20. This is not a easy to solve with a batch file because of cmd.exe is designed for running commands and executables and has nearly no string functions as more modern script interpreters like PowerShell or VBScript, but it is possible to do it with a batch file. One thing is still unclear: How to identify from the existing files in the current working directory which files to rename and which files have already the correct name with the correct prefix?

The examples defines implicit a rule like: "The files with an incremented file number are those which have one or more digits (characters in ASCII range 0 to 9) at end of the file name left to the file extension." That is a very vague rule as this rule needs the knowledge of a human being collected over years. Example: The folder contains the files Birthday Party 2023.jpg, Paris Trip 2022.jpg, Party Photos 01.jpg, Party Photos 02.jpg, Party Photos 03.jpg, Trips Photo 0100.jpg, Trips Photo 0101.jpg and so on.

The simple rule as defined above would select Birthday Party 2023.jpg as the file with highest number left to file extension, would define Birthday Party as prefix and 2023 as the currently highest file number and would next rename all the other files to Birthday Party 2024.jpg, Birthday Party 2025.jpg, … A human being with the knowledge learned over years knows that this is not right. But how should a batch script know that? The batch script does not know the meaning of the characters in the file names for human beings.

It is possible to first search in the current working directory for image files of which file name ends with one or more digits and get the strings left to the number at end of each file name. If all files ending with a number have the same string at the beginning which can be also an empty string (no prefix), the batch script has identified the file names to keep, more or less as it could be necessary to add one or even more leading zeros on existing file names if the renaming of the remaining files results in an increase of the number of digits.

There could be Photo 01.jpg, Photo 02.jpg, … Photo 98.jpg and three more files with other names must be renamed now to Photo 099.jpg, Photo 100.jpg and Photo 101.jpg which requires an additional rename of the already existing Photo *.jpg for inserting a leading zero having finally Photo 001.jpg, Photo 002.jpg, … Photo 098.jpg, Photo 099.jpg, Photo 100.jpg and Photo 101.jpg. But what should the batch file do in the use case described above with multiple files have a file name ending with a number?

I agree that if the files I'm trying to rename were named like those you listed above: Birthday Party 2023.jpg, Paris Trip 2022.jpg, Party Photos 01.jpg etc. then this would be a problem. But the files I'll be renaming will not have names like that. So something like the rule that you gave above would work. However, the pre-existing files in the folder will sometimes have text after the number, for example, A-0001 - Test or 001 (Sample) So the rule needs to allow for that. I realize I didn't say this in the post. That was an oversight on my part. Sorry, I'll edit the post to include it.

Regarding your comment about adding a leading zero when going from Photo 99 to Photo 100, the script could do exactly as you say and perform an additional rename of the already existing Photo *.jpg to make Photo 01.jpg Photo 02.jpg … Photo 99.jpg become Photo 001.jpg Photo 002.jpg … Photo 099.jpg. If this is problematic or not doable, the script could just stop working when it reaches the end of "filling" the leading zeros. So if it started at Photo 01.jpg the bat would rename up to Photo 99.jpg but then stop renaming files beyond that.

There can be used the following with command rem commented batch file for the image file renaming task with usage of an incremented file number beginning with either 0001 or the four digit number found in an image file beginning with T- or t- separated by a space or one of these characters -.()_ incremented by one. The batch file does not work for numbers in file names with less than four digits or more than four digits. It is further important that no image file beginning case-insensitive with T- has something other than a four digit number next in file name as otherwise this batch file would not work. There would be necessary some enhancements on these requirements are not fulfilled by the image file names in current working directory.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the file number with initial value 0.
set "FileNumber=0"

rem Find the highest number in T-* image file names.
for /F "tokens=2 delims=-.()_ " %%I in ('dir T-*.jpg T-*.jpeg T-*.png /A-D-L /B /O-N 2^>nul') do set "FileNumber=%%I" & goto HaveNumber

rem Remove all leading zeros from the highest file number for getting the
rem file number value interpreted as decimal and not as octal number. It
rem is possible that the environment variable FileNumber is not defined
rem anymore after this operation on still having the initial value 0 which
rem does not matter for the following code. The arithmetic expression used
rem next with FileNumber uses value 0 on no environment variable FileNumber
rem defined on evaluation of the arithmetic expression.

:HaveNumber
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%I in ("%FileNumber%") do set "FileNumber=%%I"

rem Is there any file system entry with an exclamation mark?
if exist "*!*" goto ExtendedRename

rem It is possible to use permanently enabled delayed variable expansion
rem as there is no file system entry with an exclamation mark in name.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Rename new image files of which name does not beginn case-insensitive
rem with T-. It is important to get first all file names to change loaded
rem into the memory of the running CMD process before starting the rename
rem operation as otherwise it could happen, especially on FAT32 and exFAT,
rem formatted storage medias, that a file is skipped or there is tried to
rem rename a file more than once.

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.jpg *.jpeg *.png /A-D-L /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /L /V /C:"T-"') do (
    set /A FileNumber+=1
    set "NextNumber=000!FileNumber!"
    ren "%%I" "T-!NextNumber:~-4!%%~xI"
)

endlocal
goto EndBatch

rem There is at least one directory, file or link which contains an exclamation
rem mark. It is necessary for that reason to get first assigned the file name
rem to an environment variable while delayed variable expansion is disabled
rem for getting the exclamation mark interpreted as literal character and not
rem as beginning/end of a delayed expanded variable reference and then enable
rem the required delayed variable expansion, rename the file and disable it
rem again. This is slower because of the memory copy operations done in the
rem background on every execution of setlocal and memory free operations on
rem every execution of endlocal.

:ExtendedRename
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.jpg *.jpeg *.png /A-D-L /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /L /V /C:"T-"') do (
    set "FileName=%%I"
    set /A FileNumber+=1
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "NextNumber=000!FileNumber!"
    ren "!FileName!" "T-!NextNumber:~-4!%%~xI"
    endlocal
)

:EndBatch
endlocal

For testing was used a directory with the following files:
  ; Portable Network Graphic.png
Development & Test 100% (!).jpg
T-0001.jpg
T-0002.jpeg
T-0003.png
T-0004.png
T-0005.jpeg
T-0008.png
whatever.jpeg

The files with number 0006 and 0007 do not exist anymore.
The files are named as follows after the batch file execution:
T-0001.jpg
T-0002.jpeg
T-0003.jpg
T-0004.png
T-0005.jpeg
T-0008.png
T-0009.png
T-0010.jpg
T-0011.jpeg

The file   ; Portable Network Graphic.png is renamed to T-0009.png.
The file Development & Test 100% (!).jpg is renamed to T-0010.jpg.
The file whatever.jpeg is renamed T-0011.jpeg.
Read the Microsoft documentation about Using command redirection operators for an explanation of 2>nul and |. The redirection operators > and | must be escaped with caret character ^ on the FOR command lines to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes these command lines before executing command FOR which executes the embedded dir command line with findstr for filtering with using a separate command process started in background with %ComSpec% /c and the command line enclosed in ' appended as additional arguments.
To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

dir /?
echo /?
endlocal /?
findstr /?
for /?
goto /?
if /?
rem /?
set /?
setlocal /?

See also:

How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?
Variables are not behaving as expected for understanding why delayed variable expansion is needed at all.
This answer for details about the commands SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL and what they do in background on each execution.
Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file for an explanation of unconditional command operator &.
The general issue chapters in this answer explaining what to avoid for a good coded batch script.
Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line? It explains the reason for the recommended usage of the syntax set "variable=value" for the (re)definition of an environment variable.`


Thank you! This works perfectly for image files that begin with T-. However, like I said in my original post, I'd like this script to work for whatever preexisting files are in the folder, regardless of what prefix they have (or none at all, like if it’s just a numeric sequence), and for both image files (.jpg .jpeg .png) and video files (.avi .flv .mp4 .mpg .mpeg .qt .webm .wmv) files. I just used T- as a test. Like I said above, my plan was to get it to work for just images and a single prefix first, then modify it to work for video files as well and any prefix, or no prefix at all.

I know how to make it work for video files. I just need to add the video extensions .avi .flv .mp4 .mpg .mpeg .qt .webm .wmv to the line with the image extensions. Moreover, I realize I can modify the script manually to change the prefix to replace T- with whatever I want, but it would be ideal to have the script be able to do this automatically for whatever prefix the files in the folder already have without requiring a modification to the script. Also, if there is no prefix, I'm not sure how to make the script just rename using the 4 digit number sequence.

I edited my question to hopefully more clearly explain what I'm after. Thank you for your continued help. I really appreciate it!
